# Contact Form 7 Spacing

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have the following layout: 
[image: Contact Form 7]

I want to reduce the space between each field, so that e.g. the space between "Ihr Name" field and the "Ihre Firma" field is less.

This is the code I use:

```
[text* name placeholder "Ihr Name"]
[text company placeholder "Ihre Firma"]
[email* your-email placeholder "Ihre E-Mail"]
[text* your-subject placeholder "Betreff"]
```

Answer (score 4):

to reduce the spacing, you're probably going to have to use a little CSS.

If you can post a link to the website, I can give you a more precise prescription. But presumably, the following will work:

```
.wpcf7 p {margin-bottom:10px;}
```

Comment: Hey. Could you please tell me in which file I would insert that line of code?

Comment: A most likely place would be your theme's style.css file. If you're not familiar with the theme, or FTP, you could use a plugin like Simple Custom CSS: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

Install **contact form 7 customize** first, and then go to: *Personalization*>*CF7 Customizer*>*Custom CSS* in your wordpress page.
And put it the code like James Ryven Valeii added:

```
.wpcf7 p {margin-bottom:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

to reduce the space between form fields use margin.

example :

`.wpcf7-form .wpcf7-text {margin-bottom: -20px;}`

note : you may add wanna add margin for button later on.

Answer (score -5):

go to the Contact Form and type:

```
<p>[text* your-name placeholder"Name (Required)"] </p>

<p>[email* your-email placeholder"Email (Required)"] </p>

<p>[tel* tel-346 placeholder"Contact Number (required)"] </p>

<p>[textarea your-message placeholder"Your Message"] </p>

[submit "Send"]
```